# Javascript: How to get the max value in input range?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the max attribute value in javascript on change. Thanks

HTML

```
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1"  id="slide_default" >
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function(){

    var slide_default = document.getElementById("slide_default");

    $('#slide_default').change(function(){

        range_default.innerHTML = slide_default.value
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("slide_default").setAttribute("max", 42);
var max = document.getElementById("slide_default").getAttribute("max");
```

and since you are using jQuery in your question you can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#slide_default").attr("max", 42);
var val = $("#slide_default").attr("max");
```